# Is there a way to generate an rss feed with all questions that get 10+ upvotes?

Tags: support, feeds, searching

I know there is a way to get ALL questions through a feed, but what about great questions? Are they listed independently somewhere?

If not, can I do it with a yahoo pipe? Any cues as to how I should do it?

I thought about this today, because some questions contain extremely nice insight, and I clearly don't check the site often enough to see them all.

Comment: I don't know about a feed, but you can [search](http://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=votes:10%20views:0) for them, sorting by newest.  However, a much older question could reach +10 and then be added to the list, so page 42, for example, might suddenly get new entries.

Answer (score 2):

Not built in; you might check http://stackapps.com to see if there are any RSS apps that will work.